# Prevent aluminium vapour condensing on a surface

Tags: thermodynamics, vacuum, phase-transition, condensation

I have a situation where aluminium vapour is created in a vacuum chamber ($10^{-6}\ \mathrm{mbar}$). I would like a window to look into the chamber; however, the aluminium vapour produced condenses on the window, clouding it up.

So I thought, why not heat up the window above the boiling point of the aluminium? I would like to use sapphire for the window, but it has a melting point of around $2000\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, lower than the boiling point of the aluminium which is closer to $2500\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$. If the sapphire got that hot it wouldn't function very well I don't think.

However, does it need to be that hot? When you de-mist a window in a car, you heat it up, but only up to about $20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$, nowhere near the boiling point of the water, would it be the same for aluminium? **How hot does a surface need to be for condensation to cease to be noticeable** (for water or Al)?

*(And can you think of any other solutions to the problem of the window deposits?)*

Comment: Two quick points. In the water vapour analogy, the water *partial* pressure is lower than 1 atm. In vacuum the BP of the Al is considerably *depressed*.

Comment: The classic method is to use a periscope-like arrangement of two metal-coated glass slides placed in front of the window shielding it from direct deposition. The first, aimed toward the sample or crucible reflects to the second glass slide pointed toward the human or camera viewer. Deposition on the sample-facing slide just keeps making a nice mirror, deposition on the back side of the second slide does nothing. Source: running way too many crucible/e-beam/sputter deposition systems in my life...

Comment: @JonCuster That's very interesting, because that was the idea I came up with, but when I asked a Physicist he speculated that the finish would be cloudy/matte from the deposit (he also told me to ask a deposition expert though!). So you say it would be shiny, do you have any documentation (manufacturers of parts, scholarly articles etc.) that I could cite to my manager which confirm this approach? Also, from experience do you know what the macroscopic geometry is - does the vapour bead much or leave a wavy surface - as we may be using the camera for measurement, so distortion is best avoided!

Comment: If the deposition on the mirrors is cloudy and matte, it will be on your sample as well which is a bad thing. But, really, every deposition system I've ever used in the last 40 years has had some similar arrangement if you wanted to see the source. Particularly for aluminum, this is dead simple.

Comment: You can place the sensor far away from the source so before the vapor reaches the sensor you can complete most of the test.

Comment: My experience (some years ago now), evaporating metals and semi-metals in UHV systems, mirrors that of @Jon Custer. Deposition of aluminium on a smooth surface usually forms a pretty good mirror until it is exposed to air. So during deposition/condensation your mirror should remain clear unless you are depositing a very thick layer. We also usually used a small shutter (held up by an electromagnet) to shield our view-port during the period that the crucible was heating - to shield the v.p. from the initial sometimes impure gas stream.

Comment: Can you use something like "tear-away" layers on your observation window, such that you tear away a thin layer as it gets fogged up?  If you have several layers on top of each other and a means to tear them away, the method should work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the atmospheric boiling point of aluminum.  Conceptually, to prevent condensation, all that is required is for the inside surface temperature of the window to be higher than that of the aluminum within the enclosure.  To be sure, 10-20 C difference should suffice.  Of course, you need to make sure that whatever you do to heat the window doesn't also heat the aluminum inside the chamber.  .

Comment: I'm slightly confused by this line: '_[...]to prevent condensation, all that is required is for the inside surface temperature of the window to be higher than that of the aluminum within the enclosure_.' 

Isn't the temperature of the aluminium within the enclosure going to be the bpt. of the aluminium? Could you clarify - as it sounds as though you are saying the window surface has to be 10/20 C hotter than the vapour, which will necessarily be at Al bpt. already (admittedly, lowered owing to the vacuum, but still hot!)?

Comment: That is what he is saying.  Whatever the temperature, if the vapor is going to condense, enough heat has to transfer *from* the vapor *to* the window in order for the molecules landing there to change state.  If you ensure that is unlikely, they will condense elsewhere.  Heat seldom flows from a cooler place to a significantly warmer place.

Comment: It isn't the heat flow that matters.  It is the equilibrium vapor pressure at the window temperature vs the equilibrium vapor pressure at the Al inside the chamber temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Why not construct the equivalent of a windshield wiper inside of the chamber? Certainly there are materials that would function perfectly well at the temperatures in the chamber - a ceramic material for instance. You may even be ale to acquire off-the-shelf ceramic blades - in the form of household ceramic knifes etc.

You need not breach the chamber to construct a mechanism to cause the wiper to sweep across the inner surface of your window. I believe there are ceramics impregnated with magnetic particles that are commercially available. You can drive blade motion through magnetic induction. You may even be able to use a hand-held magnet to manually move the blade.

Comment: Interesting idea, although I didn't mention that this is an e-beam setup, any moving magnetic fields would be tricky to account for in the path of the electrons. Also, I'm sceptical as to the feasibility; have you any experience of something similar? I feel like the metal coating may be too thin for a wiper to be effective.

Comment: Alternatively the wiper could be mechanically driven by a watch-spring drive - The mechanism could be also be mechanically "programmed" to function at a desired time and for a desired period even for several particular days at particular times. the mechanism could be thermally insulated if needed by a ceramic casing to resist the temps in the chamber - You could conduct bench-experiments  to fine-tune the action with respect to the metal-coating thinness issue. If you found parameters that work, then you could  construct the actual mechanism with confidence that it would function as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem but with silver. I was making silver films on a glass substrate by evaporating silver in a vacuum, and just as you say the silver vapour would condense on everything inside the vacuum chamber.

I'm afraid I never found a good solution for this. In principle heating the window to above the boiling point of the metal would stop the condensation, but this is unlikely to be practical. In my case I eventually used a movable shield to protect the glass and only unshielded it for the brief periods where I wanted to look inside. The glass still needed to be removed for cleaning on a regular basis but at least it alleviated the problem a bit.

Putting any sort of moving mechanism inside a UHV chamber can be a pain, though I think if you're only working at $10^{-6}$ torr it shouldn't be too bad.